# Test AD connections with LDAP string - Azure

Tags: azure, ldap, azure-active-directory

I want to test Active Directory connection in Azure. Using LDAP connection strings, getting error "unable to establish secure connection with the server azure". Using on Microsoft Azure
I am unsure what LDAP strings are, how they can be used, where they come into testing an Active Directory.

Any clarification on this will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default azure active directory does not support LDAP. To programmatically access AAD [Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) must be used.

if you are looking at a hybrid scenario then applications like sharepoint which frequently interact with AD can make use of the on premises active directory. setting up a domain controller in an azure VM can help in having a better performance for such a case.

Comment: Thanks Aravind. Very helpful. Would I be able to test/connect an AD connection from a UAT server in Azure?