# How to create a connection string which points to Azure Active Directory in Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-config, asp.net-membership, azure-active-directory

I plan to create a connection string for my membership which points to Azure Active Directory. Here are what I've got from Azure Active Directory:

**Case 1:** The information is get from https://portal.azure.com

```
ClientId: a92a056f-????-????-????-3a86545656e2

Tenant: somedomain.onmicrosoft.com

AADInstance: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}

PostLogoutRedirectUri: http://localhost:51323/
```

**Case 2:** The information is get from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

```
App ID / Client Id: 54fadbd8-????-?????-????-0260307e24ac

Private Key: E5400125D?????????????EDA54B22CC0D8631

Redirect URL: http://localhost:51323/
```

**A sample connection string:**

```
LDAP://127.0.0.1/OU=Users,DC=somedomain.onmicrosoft.com
```

**A sample connection string from web.config:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyMembershipConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://127.0.0.1/OU=Users,DC=somedomain.onmicrosoft.com" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

***From given information above, what is the format of the connectionstring for each case? (Case 1 or 2)***

*Note: The connectionstring for azure active directory is applied on a .Net web application.*

---

---

For this question, I have another example:

**I have a domain:** somedomain.onmicrosoft.com

**I have an Azure Active Directory Account:** trin@somedomain.com

So my ConnectionString look like:

```
LDAP://somedomain.onmicrosoft.com/OU=trin@somedomain.com,OU=somedomain,DC=somedomain,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com
```

Does the connection string correct?

Comment: What do you use the connection string for?

Comment: I use for establish a connection to azure active directory.

Comment: When querying AzureAD, usually graph is used. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220482/test-ad-connections-with-ldap-string-azure

Comment: Graph API is the *only* way to query Azure AD - you cannot connect via LDAP.

Comment: Your comment makes scene. Please make an answer for this question, I will late make it as answered.